# Replace a value in SQL instead of creating a second one with same name

Tags: java, mysql

sorry I'm a beginner (and French), I searched around the Internet but I did not find an answer.

Here's my problem (I'm working on Java) : I've a table with two columns (`playername` and `id`).

To add values I use this command :

```
INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`playername`, `id`) VALUES ('" + player + "', '" + randomString + "')
```

`player` and `randomString` are variables. Every time the command is used by the `player`, a new (random) `id` is given, but instead of updating the `id` corresponding to the `playername`, it create a new row with the same `playername`.

What I want is to update the `id` if the `playername` is already in the table.

Would you help me ?

Comment: you can't update ids

Comment: i want to update the second column if the value in the first column already exists. id is 8 random characters. That must be possible ?

Comment: Index the playername and see INSERT... UPDATE syntax

Comment: Sounds Like you are trying to do a Merge

Answer (score 0):

Okey so I found the solution.

I used INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.
I thought that the 1st column was the primary key, but I had to set it with phpmyadmin, now it works !

Thanks for the help.